# why we need to use get method inside a java file @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

Tags: java, spring

In generally while sending form data from the ui pages we are using method="GET" or method="POST" in the form tag then what is the use of these methods in the server side programs. I am using these methods in spring while calling the methods in the controller @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

Can anyone explain what is the real use of get or post methods in server side code

Comment: You usually don't need to specify GET on the server side. As for when you use each, it's exactly the same as when you use them on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking, if the purpose of your method is to retrieve data from the server use GET. e.g. getting information to display on the client.

If you are sending data to the server use POST. e.g. sending information to the server to be saved on a database somewhere.

There is a limit to the size of data you can send to the server with a GET request.

Comment: Thanks James, but we can specify the same methods from client itself while calling the methods what is the point of using inside the method

Answer (score 0):

The server side GET or POST is used to specify what the server expects to receive in order to accept the request. The client side GET or POST is used to specify what will be sent to the server. These two must match. You cannot send a GET request when server expects a POST and vice-versa.
When you are building a server application, it is important to know the appropriate request type to use, which by itself is a whole big different topic which you should research if it is you the one that builds the server side part.